# WebMethod is not called but ajax request return whole page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

I am using jQuery to call a server side method. My scenario is am checking the user activity on the browser and if no action is made after certain amount of time, a timeout function is called which will call a server side function to log the user out.

I am using a web method and have followed multiple tutorials but it is not working as of now. The AJAX request error and in the response the whole page is being returned.

Note also that I have a break point in the web method function which is never being hit.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).idleTimer(10000);

  $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'BasePage.aspx/ValidateUser',
      crossDomain: true,
      data: "{ 'foo': 'AJAX Test' }",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data, status) {
        alert(status + " " + data.d)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("error!")
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on("active.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj, triggerevent) {
    // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
  });
});
```

```csharp
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ValidateUser(string foo) 
{
  // breakpoint not being hit
}
```

I have my scriptmanager set up in master page as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
```

Comment: The 'whole page' being returned to your error sounds more like a YSOD, which will have an error message and call stack in it which you can debug. Check exactly what the content of this response is.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I tried to ouput the error in the alert and i get " jQuery33108663481583276744_1567423440395 was not called"

Comment: That means that the response is not JSONP. I'm not sure why you're using that anyway as this is a local request, and it's a POST which JSONP doesn't support. Change the `dataType` to match whatever format you return data in. Also remove `crossDomain`, and send an actual object to `data`, ie. `data: { foo: 'AJAX Test' }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i did the modification,still not working

Comment: What error do you get now??

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan same error.no breakpoint is hit. Is there another way just to call a server side function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i replace the ajax request by  PageMethods.ValidateUser(Success, onerror)    still getting the same error

Comment: What i eventually did just for the sake of making it work(bad way) is create a  button and adding an onclick event. i make my javascript call the click event of that button which works like a charm.